# SharePoint -- how to get item-id from ListItem?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm implementing an Azure function with SharePoint webhook.

When the hook triggered, I could get the ListItem Id like 1 or 2 or 3 etc.

Then I could retrieve the ListItem by following code, so I could get some info like file type & file name:

```
var listItem = list.GetItemById(1);
cc.Load(listItem);
cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

**How to download item via graph API when I just know list Id? As it needs item-id (string) instead of list id (int).**

```
await graphClient.Sites["site-id"]
.Drives["drive-id"]
.Items["012SCX46B5IUJGUVDKNJGI3LU2....."]
.Content
.Request(queryOptions)
.GetAsync();
```

**item-id is like 012SCX46B5IUJGUVDKNJGI....., but the listItem id is identity like 1 or 2 or 3.**

Updates:
Maybe specify the path & file name could resolve the issue. So it didn't need the item-id...

```
await graphClient.Sites["site-id"]
.Drives["drive-id"]
.Root
.ItemWithPath("Document.docx")
.Content
.Request(queryOptions)
.GetAsync();
```

Thanks